# How can my docker CLI application read a file from host?

Tags: docker

I made a simple command line app in go language to read a file and process it. I am trying to use docker to run the application. In the program, the first argument to the code is the file name with the location. Now the problem is I am not able to understand how can the contatiner code read a file from the local system. I am using the following docker codes to build and run the application:

```
docker build . -t go-dock
docker run -p 3000:3000 go-dock file/file.json
```

`file/file.json` is complete file name with file path in my case.
I read about volumes but I understood that only a container can save data there. The problem is I want to read the file. So how can I do that?

Comment: Can you run your application directly, without packaging it in a container?  (One of the design goals of Docker is that container applications can't easily access host files.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I can run my application directly and it works fine. Actually this is an assignment and it specifically says me to dockerise the application and the file name should be given while running it.

Answer (score 1):

you can read a local file by mounting it
See https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ for documentation on the subject.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v file/file.json:mnt/file.json go-dock
```

mount files according to you , so that you can read them in container as well as in local file system too